# sqlalchemy select returning list of tuples with one element while declarative select returns list of elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a model that I'm creating properties as helpers to run common queries.

One of them is a declarative select on the model (I think that's the proper vocab, but please let me know if I'm describing anything incorrectly!):

```py
class Device:
    id = Column(Integer)
    children = relationship(Children)
    
    @property
    def active_children(self):
        return self.children.filter(Children.status=='active').all()
```

This example is returning a list of children objects such as

```py
[<Children obj>,
 <Children obj>,
...]
```

But I also have a more complex query property that I ended up writing using the generative select method:

```py
@property
def problem_children(self):
    stmt = select(Children).\
                 join(Issues, 
                     and_(Children.id == Issues.device_child_id,
                          Issues.log_ts.between(Children.activate_ts, Children.deactivate_ts)).\
                 filter(Children.status == 'active').\
                 filter(Issues.type == 1).\
                 filter(Issues.user != 'SYS').\
                 order_by(Children.name)
    return db.session.execute(stmt).all()
```

This returns a list of tuples with only one Children object:

```py
[(<Children obj>,),
 (<Children obj>,),
...]
```

I can solve this by instead setting the last line to a list comprehension instead of using `all()` but that feels not-elegant. I've been looking through the documentation and I haven't found the answer yet, any insight would be greatly helpful!

```py
@property
def problem_children(self):
    stmt = ...
    return [x[0] for x in db.session.execute(stmt)]
```

(note the above code is untested since it's adapted from my situation, sorry if there's typos or issues other than my described issue!)

My question: is there a better way to standardize my property returns so that my property API stays consistent?

Comment: Just add `.scalars()` to the result: `return db.session.execute(stmt).scalars().all()`.
---
*See [scalars](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Result.scalars)*

Comment: @van I don't know why but I thought that would instead flatten the object to the constituent column values... still more reading to do!